# How to specify required function on generic selector in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

I know this can be done but I can't remember (or locate) the syntax for the life of me. How can I specify that a specific function must be present on a generic type in a function definition?

For instance, I know I can do this:

```
def blah[A](p: A)
```

What I really want is something like this (but my syntax is all wrong of course):

```
def blah[A(someFunction)](p: A)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if using this is a good idea, but here is how it works:

```
def blah[A <: { def someFunction: String }](a: A) : Unit = 
    println(a.someFunction)

scala> class Test { def someFunction: String = "hello" }
defined class Test

scala> blah(new Test)
hello

scala> class Test2
defined class Test2

scala> blah(new Test2)
<console>:16: error: inferred type arguments [Test2] do not conform to method blah's type parameter bounds [A <: AnyRef{def someFunction: String}]
```

Note that this feature (so-called structural types) uses reflection, and has to be enabled using the language import `import scala.language.reflectiveCalls`

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is called a "structural type".

Any example from here: https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html

```
scala> def foo(x: { def get: Int }) = 123 + x.get
foo: (x: AnyRef{def get: Int})Int

scala> foo(new { def get = 10 })                 
res0: Int = 133
```

Note, however, that this is going to be slower than just declaring a `trait` that requiring that any argument implements that trait.